# Split routing config files by host

Tags: routes, symfony-2.3

I have this routing.yml

```
backend_routes:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_backend.yml"
    host: "backend.com"

frontend_routes:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_frontend.yml"
    host: "frontend.com"
```

But routing knows hothing about %kernel.root_dir% parameter. How i can set it parameter to routing.yml?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am mistaken but for what I know you don't need to set the %kernel.root_dir% parameter as it is set elsewhere in the project folder and already known. In file `YourProject\app\bootstrap.php.cache` you have

`protected function getKernelParameters()
    {
        $bundles = array();
        foreach ($this->bundles as $name => $bundle) {
            $bundles[$name] = get_class($bundle);
        }
        return array_merge(
            array(
                'kernel.root_dir'        => $this->rootDir,
                'kernel.environment'     => $this->environment,
                'kernel.debug'           => $this->debug,
                'kernel.name'            => $this->name,
                'kernel.cache_dir'       => $this->getCacheDir(),
                'kernel.logs_dir'        => $this->getLogDir(),
                'kernel.bundles'         => $bundles,
                'kernel.charset'         => $this->getCharset(),
                'kernel.container_class' => $this->getContainerClass(),
            ),
            $this->getEnvParameters()
        );
    }`

If you find the string "kernel.root_dir" (using Notepad++ for example) in your project you will find many places where this parameter is set in defaults and third-party bundles.

Nevertheless in general if you want to set a parameter value you should find file `YourProject\app\config\parameters.yml` (if you chose yml as the bundle configuration format). Add there your key without %% and its value.

```
parameters:
    my.param: 25
```

If your config was done in xml, use

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="my.param">25</parameter>
</parameters>
```

and you are done.